# PDO IN() Array Statement AND a placeholder

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, warnings

I found this code on SO, which is great for using PDO and the IN() statement together.

```
$values = explode(',', $values) ; # 1,4,7

$placeholders = rtrim(str_repeat('?, ', count($values)), ', ') ;
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN ($placeholders)";

$stm = $db->prepare($query) ;
$stm->execute($values) ;
```

However, how can I mix in another addition to the query so the query looks like this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN ($placeholders) AND product=?";
$stm = $db->prepare($query) ;
$stm->execute(array($values,$product)) ; //error happens when adding product placeholder
```

I thought this would work but I get:

**Warning:** PDOStatement::execute() [pdostatement.execute]: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in line 3 (the $stm line)

Any idea how to get this to behave as intended?

**UPDATED** execute to array, still not working..

Comment: This `rtrim(str_repeat('?, ', count($values)), ', ') ;` is nice.
thank you :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Solution

This should work, if `$values` is an array:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN ($placeholders) AND product=?";
$stm->execute(array_merge($values, array($product)));
```

### Explanation

`execute()` expects one parameter - in this case an array - to be provided. By adding `array_merge($values, array($product))` you create one array with `$product` added at the end, so the query should work correctly.

See the demo here: http://ideone.com/RcClX

Answer (score 6):

> ```
> $stm->execute($values,$product) ; //error happens when adding product placeholder
> ```

The problem here is that `execute` needs a *single* array.  You can't pass multiple arrays, and worse, you can't nest arrays.

We already have a perfectly good `$values` array, so let's reuse it *after* you create the placeholder string.

```
$values = explode(',', $values) ; # 1,4,7

$placeholders = rtrim(str_repeat('?, ', count($values)), ', ') ;
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN ($placeholders) AND product=?";

// New!
$values[] = $product;

$stm = $db->prepare($query);
$stm->execute($values);
```

Comment: This looks like the most efficient answer so far, same thing as Tadeck's answer but cleaner execute statement with a single array. It should always also know that the product=? placeholder will always be the extra value not in the count, am I right? One more thing if so, if we were to add an additional item at the end of the query, such as, AND type=?, do we just say $values[] = $type; after the $values[] = $product; line, or can we merge them in one line? Something like, $values[] = ($product,$type); maybe?

Comment: @Maverick: I did that (merged arrays within `execute()` call) on purpose, because you can always use `$values` in your code later. And if you do it after you append `$product`, then you will just need to deal with one additional element you did not want there :) But the decision is yours - just remember not to make the code complicated :) If you want to do something like `$values[] = ($product,$type)` in one line, just do this: `$values = array_merge($values, array($product,$type))`.

Comment: @Tadeck: Both Tadeck's & Charles answers are excellent. I wish I can accept both on SO.

Comment: @bart: Using `array_splice()` means that you will first add some elements only to remove them later, to return `$values` to its original value. Not very efficient and, more importantly, may decrease (and probably will decrease) maintainability. But `array_slice()` is something one can take into consideration.

Answer (score 1):

And an other solution can be (if you like the :param_name = $value way, as me):

```
$params = array(
     ':product' =>  $product
);
$_in_params = array();
foreach ( $_in_values as $idx_in => $value_in)
{
    $_in_params[] = ':param_in_'.$idx_in;
    $params[':param_in_'.$idx_in] = $value_in;
}

$query .= "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (".join(',',$_in_params).") AND product=:product";
```

I'm not sure if this is the best and the most optimal solution, but it's a little bit more human readable :) And it can be helpful if you have a big an complicated query and you want to debug it

*(I'm curious if someone have a good argument why NOT to do in this way)*

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to prepare it ^_^

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN ($placeholders) AND product=?";
$stm = $db->prepare($query) ;
$stm->execute($values,$product) ; //p00f
```

And **aside from that** `execute()` should only have **one parameter**

So the above **won't work *AT ALL*!**

[See the DOCs](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php)

Comment: Thanks Neal, however, I did prepare it, I was just showing the parts that changed between the two calls. I also changed it to use: $stm->execute(array($values,$product)); and I still get an error, I'll reedit and post above

Answer (score 0):

Placeholders version if you need it

```
$values = [1, 4, 7, 8];
$placeholders =  preg_filter('/^/', ':prefix_', array_keys($values)));
$query = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN ( '. implode(', ', $placeholders) . ')';

$stmt = $db->prepare($query);

if (count($values) > 0) {
    foreach ($values as $key => $current_value) {
        $stmt->bindValue($placeholders[$key] , $current_value, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    }
}

$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```