# PHQL "WHERE xxx IN ()" can get only 1 data

Tags: php, mysql, phalcon

I'm creating a RESTful API with Phalcon.
I want to get some data from "Shop" table by IDs.
PHP code:

```
$app->post('/api/shops/search', function () use ($app) {
    $ids_shop = $app->request->getJsonRawBody();
    $ids = array();
    foreach($ids_shop as $id){
            $ids[] = $id->id_shop;
    }
    $ids_str = implode(",", $ids);
    $shops = getShopsData($ids_str, $app);

    return $shops;
});

function getShopsData($ids_shop, $app) {
    $phql = "SELECT * FROM Shops WHERE Shops.id IN ( :ids: )";
    $shops = $app->modelsManager->executeQuery($phql, array(
        'ids' => $ids_shop
    ));
    return $shops;
}
```

Test:

```
curl -i -X POST -d '[{"id_shop":1},{"id_shop":2}]' http://localhost/sample/api/shops/search
```

However I can get only one data whose id is 1. And I also tried it:

```
curl -i -X POST -d '[{"id_shop":2},{"id_shop":1}]' http://localhost/sample/api/shops/search
```

This returns one data whose id is 2.

Why cannot I get multiple data? My log says $ids_str = "1,2", so I think phql query might be correct...

Comment: I tried there but they didn't effect.

Comment: Your bound parameter is `:ids:` - is that a typo? You don't need the trailing colon, so it should be `:ids`.

Comment: Thanx, but I have already tried it and it didn't effect.

Comment: Alright; and have you tried changing your code along the lines of the duplicate that Barmar found? If you have, could you please edit you question, and include the code you're using now?

Comment: Wow, I found a solution to this problem.
`$phql = "SELECT * FROM Shops WHERE Shops.id IN ( $ids_shop )";` If I don't bind parameter, I could get correct data.

Comment: You're also leaving yourself open to SQL injection.

Comment: It is not a duplicate and there is one more answer available in case of Phalcon: `$this->modelsManager->createBuilder()->inWhere('column', $array);`

Comment: @yergo Thanks a lot! I can get several data by that way.

Comment: Reopening because it seems, from the comments, that there are phalcon specific solutions to this problem, which are not specified in the dupe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there are few examples working with both PDO and PHQL [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26845787/pdo-bind-array-to-where-in) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8991688/pdo-in-array-statement-and-a-placeholder) that suites to your example, there is one more approach possible in Phalcon queryBuilder mechanism:

```
$builder = $this->modelsManager->createBuilder();
$builder->addFrom('Application\Entities\KeywordsTrafficReal', 'tr')
        ->leftJoin('Application\Entities\Keywords', 'kw.id = tr.keyword_id', 'kw')
        ->inWhere('keyword_id', self::$keywords) // <<< it is an array!
        ->betweenWhere('traffic_date', self::$daterange['from'], self::$daterange['to']);
```

`inWhere` method is reachable only via queryBuilder as far as i know and it works exactly the same way as mentioned PDO examples `IN (?, ?, ?)`. But you are not in need of implementing it by hand.

You can also skip part of creating PHQL and drive directly to create SQL query, but on cost of making own validations.

```
$realModel = new KeywordsTrafficReal();

$sql = sprintf('SELECT * '
            .  'FROM keywords_traffic_real tr '
            .  'LEFT JOIN keywords kw '
            .  'ON kw.id = tr.keyword_id '
            .  'WHERE tr.keyword_id IN(%s) '
            .  "AND traffic_date BETWEEN '%s' AND '%s' ",
        join(',', self::$keywords), self::$daterange['from'], self::$daterange['to']);

$results = new \Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Resultset\Simple(null, $realModel, $realModel->getReadConnection()->query($sql));
```